# Gmail action button not working when I try to send using smtp settings

Tags: google-schemas

I am exploring gmail action button. Am sending an email from my gmail account using rails application ( gmail SMTP settings ) to my self and another domain.

but I am not able to see gmail action button. But if I send email from script.google.com to my self only, it is showing.

I have also checked header from received email and found that it is passing both SPF and DKIM checks. But still not able to see button.

Email header is https://gist.github.com/rahul100885/c8ad31f2c6a8e0542a67

Also I tried to whilelist my email address as mentioned here https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1 but whitelist email is bouncing.

Is it, I am missing any setting?

Comment: Please add the email headers to the question

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino updated question with email header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The from: and to: addresses don't match, and your sender address is not whitelisted, that explains why the action button is not showing.

We keep getting whitelisting requests from the form you linked, you may have hit a transient issue, so I'd recommend trying again.

Comment: but when you send from: and to: address will always be different. Also to is hosted on google apps service. Is it white listing is only reason?

Comment: You can send emails to yourself and have from: and to: match. If they don't match, then you need whitelisting.

Comment: Do we need DKIM/SPF signing even when self testing? I'm trying to send mail to myself to my gmail address over SMTP (I don't have a domain, so can't sign it), and actions don't appear. The markup is right because I've validated it

Comment: Yes, you need DKIM/SPF signing.